# Почему slideToggle работает не корректно?

Tags: jquery

Есть сайт elemis.com.ua. На разрешении экрана меньше 480 есть мобильное меню, внутри которого есть пункты и выпадающее подменю. При клике на иконку "+" slideToggle не корректно работает. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?
Фрагмент js

```
$(".megamenu-plus").on('click', function(){
$(this).parent().children('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(500);
})
```

Фрагмент HTML(нужно чтобы по клику на + плавно выезжало/пряталось меню dropdown-menu)

```
<li class="dropdown middle">
<a href="/novinki/" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-img" data-toggle="dropdown">Новинки</a>
<span class="megamenu-plus"></span>
<div class="dropdown-menu megamenu-type-html"></div>
</li>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте сюда сниппет демонстрирующий проблему. никто не будет на вашем сайте искать фрагменты кода отвечающие за это меню и догадываться что вообще неправильно и как вы хотите чтобы было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле megamenu.js находится ваша проблема

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(500).fadeIn(10);
},
function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(10).fadeOut(10);
});
```